# Map between two Blow-ups

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, blowup

Let $\widetilde{X}$ denote the blow-up of a scheme $X$ with respect to a sheaf of ideals $\mathcal{I}$. Let $Y$ be a closed subscheme of $X$, such that  $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{O}_Y$ (the inverse image ideal sheaf) is invertible. Does there exist a map $f: BL_Y(X)\rightarrow \widetilde{X}$ such that $\pi_1f=\pi_2$, where $\pi_1:\widetilde{X} \rightarrow X $ and $\pi_2:BL_Y(X) \rightarrow X$ are the blow-up maps?

To get such a map we have to show $\mathcal{I}\mathcal{O}_{BL_Y(X)}$ is invertible via the map $\pi_2$ which I am unable to show.

Comment: No. Take $X = \mathbb P^1$, $p,q \in X$ distinct points, $\mathcal I = \mathcal I_p$ and $Y = q$.

Comment: @RijulSaini I am new to this topic.Could you please tell me what is denoted by $\mathcal{I}_p$. Does that mean blowing up the line at points p and q,both resulting in $\mathbb{P}^1$

Comment: Yeah $\mathcal I_p$ is not a standard notation, I meant the ideal of the point $p$. Anyway, your $\widetilde X$ will be the blow up at $p$ so the blow up at $q$ will not factor through $\widetilde X$. Also I think you should take $X = \mathbb A^2$ instead of $\mathbb P^1$.